# Nest JS add another secret key to refresh token with @nestjs/jwt

Tags: nestjs, jwt

I'm trying to make authentication with access and refresh tokens on NestJs. As i saw in nestjs documentation i should register my secret key in auth module. I did that.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'RefreshToken', schema: RefreshTokenSchema }]),
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

This secret key is used when im creating my tokens in auth service.

```
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: '60s'});
const refreshToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: '24h' });
```

When im trying to set secret key in this.jwtService.sign function
like

```
const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload, 'secretkey' ,{ expiresIn: '60s'})
```

I've got error. It tells me that function can get only two arguments.
So how can create two secret keys and use each other for proper token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly. It appears you're trying to have two separate strategies for signing two different types of token? If so, you just need to use multiple named strategies.

Inside of your declarations, you might do something like the following:

```js
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'accessToken') {}
```

```js
export class JwtStrategy2 extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'refreshToken') {}
```

Now, with the two different names, you can also specify your default strategy. Which seems to be your access token.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'RefreshToken', schema: RefreshTokenSchema }]),
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'accessToken' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy, JwtStrategy2],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And that should allow you to perform the imports from your constructor with the two service types.

And then your above code should work for signing with different times by calling each service individually for its assigned task! I didn't run this code, but it should work with a little bit of tweaking.

Comment: I have a similar issue. But I need different timeouts for each strategy. Is it possible?

Comment: Couldn't you just change the token signing in the service?

Comment: How can I use the second `jwtService` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

@nestjs/jwt JwtService allows you to pass options to the sign() method.

you can just...

```
let token = this.jwtService.sign(payload);
let refreshToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload, {
  secret: jwtConstants.jwt_refresh_secret,
  expiresIn: jwtConstants.jwt_refresh_expire
});
```

`token` uses params you registered the service with and `refreshToken` will use alternate params